# Use Rvest Xpath to scrape multiple embedded urls on a page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm having trouble returning anything from the following

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)


url <- 'https://www.psacard.com/pop#2Basketball%20Cards%7Cmichael%20jordan%201997'

read_html(url) %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = 'table[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]')
```

Ultimately, I want to scrape the url from each of the blue hyperlinks in the table from this page. For example, the first one would be 'https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1995-98/upper-deck-authenticated-michael-jordan-commemorative/212522'

So the end product would be an object with all of the links from that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That table is a javascript-based render of a JSON, which in turn is fetched from `https://www.psacard.com/pop/essearch` by a `POST` request. We can make the same call with `httr2` and construct those URLs:

```r
library(httr2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
request("https://www.psacard.com/pop/essearch") %>% 
  # submit search parameters as form fields
  req_body_form(search = "michael jordan 1997",
                draw = 1,
                filterCategoryID = 2,
                categoryName = "Basketball Cards",
                pageNumber = 1,
                pageSize = 50,
                searchSequence = 1) %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  # parse response as JSON
  resp_body_json() %>%
  # extract "data" list and build URL from each item
  pluck("data") %>% 
  map_chr(\(d) paste("https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards", 
                     d$YearIssued, d$SetNameSEO, d$HeadingID, sep = "/")) %>% 
  tibble(url = .)
#> # A tibble: 50 × 1
#>    url                                                                          
#>    <chr>                                                                        
#>  1 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1995-98/upper-deck-authenticate…
#>  2 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1996/ud-authenticated-bulls-1st…
#>  3 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/bowmans-best/34311         
#>  4 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/bowmans-best-mirror-image/…
#>  5 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/bowmans-best-techniques/63…
#>  6 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/collectors-choice/35013    
#>  7 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/collectors-choice-chicago-…
#>  8 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/collectors-choice-crash-ga…
#>  9 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/collectors-choice-crash-ga…
#> 10 https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1997/collectors-choice-factory-…
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>